# Remove navigation bar in sidemenu based template in Ionic/Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I created an application using the Ionic Framework and it works great. It is based on the sidemenu-template, so I always have a navigation bar on top of the application.

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-calm">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon-round" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-content>
      <a menu-close href="#/app/bla">
        <div id="profile-item">
          <i class="icon ion-card"></i> Bla
        </div>
      </a>
      <a menu-close href="#/app/register">
        <div id="profile-item">
          <i class="icon ion-card"></i> Sign-up
        </div>
      </a>
      <a menu-close href="#/app/login">
        <div id="profile-item">
          <i class="icon ion-card"></i> Login
        </div>
      </a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

app.js:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.login', {
  url: '/login',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }
  }
})

$stateProvider.state('app.start', {
  url: '/start',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',
      controller: 'StartsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

Now for the registration and login view I don't want to show the navigation bar at all. How can I remove it on specific view? I find this hard because the nav-bar is defined in menu.html which is called before the views.

Comment: you app.js is showing "ReferenceError: $stateProvider is not defined"..can you post your full codes including any js  source scripts and css scripts?

Comment: I only posted the relevant parts, because I am not going to add hundreds of lines to stackoverflow :)

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle then....?

Comment: one other way : u can remove <ion-nav-bar> from menu and add it in the only views u want..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify the routes definition in app.js:

```
$stateProvider.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})

$stateProvider.state('start', {
  url: '/start',
  templateUrl: 'templates/start.html',
  controller: 'StartsCtrl'
})
```

Only removing the toogle button did not work, as the user was still able to swipe right on the screen to show the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Simply hiding the `menu-toggle` button should do the trick for you.

Set a variable on the rootScope based on which you can show/hide the navigation bar toggle button:

```
<button ng-if="$root.isShowNav" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon-round" menu-toggle="left">
```

Set this variable's value inside your app's .run:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  // $rootScope.isShowNav = true/false based on some condition.
}
```

For example, here you could do something like this:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    if (toState.name !== "app.login" || toState.name !== "app.start") {
      $rootScope.isShowNav = true; 
    }
    else {
      $rootScope.isShowNav = false;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Only removing the toogle button did not work, as the user was still able to swipe right on the screen to show the menu.

Comment: Then you may apply this ng-if to your ion-side-menus itself